# git: How to rebase all commits by one certain author into a separate branch?

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-rebase

I'm using some code for which no SCM is used<sup>+</sup> and receive occasional updates in the form of all project files although only some of them have been changed only a bit. Up till now I just put my own changes in a git repo and solved these "updates" with a manual `git add -p` session which is getting more and more annoying with the amount of my own changes (those that are not determined to be published yet) increasing, and since luckily I did `git commit --author "the others"` for aforementioned "patches", I'd like to know:

> How can all commits made by one author be separated into a new branch?

(I don't mind rewriting history in this case, the repo is only used by me)

The ideal solution would include a merge of the others' branch into mine after every "patch", but for now a final merge at the end may suffice.

---

<sup>+</sup> yes, the Jedi *did* feel you cringe there

Comment: just a few notes to myself with what I'll try to answer this next week: `git log --reverse --pretty=format:"%H %an"
HEAD | nl`

Comment: a `git rev-list` might be more adapted to a script solution, while offering sort and limiting options which would help you isolate the right commits (here, by author). http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html

Comment: Thanks @VonC, I'll look into it after vacation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recently did this for someone:

```
git checkout -b other_work <sha1_of_where_to_rebase>
git log --reverse --author=others --format=%H <sha1_range> | xargs -n 1 git cherry-pick
```

Comment: You can add --no-merges to the log command if you have any in the range

Comment: do not use `git log` for scripting, use `git rev-list` instead

Comment: thanks, for the final merge I'd follow that by rebasing the original branch (well, a copy) onto `other_work`, then cherry-pick all these rebased commits to a new branch from `<sha1_of_here_to_rebase>` and finally merge. Maybe I'll expand this in a script after my vacation...

Comment: @knittl, can you be more specific on how to replicate the above with git rev-list.

Comment: @cheshirekow: `git rev-list --reverse --author=others <start..end> | xargs -n1 git cherry-pick` should do the trick

Comment: @knittl thank you for pandering to my laziness. Clearly, I [c|sh]ould have gotten that from the docs :D

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite understanding what you are doing, but the problem you describe with a third party codebase, is called a "vendor branch". Here is how I would handle it:

Make a branch for the third party version, e.g. `vendor`. I assume your branch is called `master`. When they publish a new version, you can do the following:

```bsh
git stash # If you have any uncommitted files
git checkout vendor
tar -xzvf [new files]  # This might be unzip or whatever, rather than tar
git commit -am "Version xxx from upstream"  # Adjust commit message to suit
git checkout master
git merge vendor   # Bring changes into your branch (you could use rebase here if you prefer to keep all your changes on top of all their changes)
git stash pop # Restore your uncommitted files
```

ps. rather than `git add -p`, I'd use `git gui`. I was sceptical of using a gui to begin with, but I couldn't live without `git gui` and `gitk` now (or `gitx` on a mac).

Comment: thanks, this is indeed the procedure now. For some reason I can't really remember I used to commit the others' changes into my master branch as well so my question was about how to retroactively split that single branch into a history that looks like I'd always branched the way you describe

Comment: At the time I answered this, I hadn't realised it was written in April last year, rather than April last month :-)