# Is it possible save my latest commit (changes) into a directory ? How?

Tags: git, github

I am working on one portion of the repository and I just want to save directory with the code which I have committed.I am looking for a command to save one particular commit into a directory. That commit may be of mine or of my team member.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git: How to rebase all commits by one certain author into a separate branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663297/git-how-to-rebase-all-commits-by-one-certain-author-into-a-separate-branch)

Comment: @PrashanthChandra it is not duplicate of that question. What I want id to save my latest commit into a directory.

Comment: Then you should update your question to clarify because that is not how it reads.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use git archive command for this

```
git archive --format zip --output src.zip ad73856aab3c37d73c1dcd657398259ae30b46df
```

here zip is the format of archive for exporting the project files.

src.zip is the path where the src is exported.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for